# Apache CXF DSOGI with JSON on Karaf

Tags: json, osgi, cxf, karaf, dosgi

I am trying to create a RESTful web service in Karaf 4.0.8 with Apache CXF DOSGI. The service is being called but I am getting this error: No message body writer has been found for class....

Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you!!!

### Component:

```
    @Component(immediate = true, property = {
            "service.exported.interfaces=*", 
            "service.exported.configs=org.apache.cxf.rs",
"org.apache.cxf.rs.provider=com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider",
            "org.apache.cxf.rs.address=/integr" })
    public class AccountRestService implements AccountWebUserIdResource {
    ...
    }


Interface:
------------
    @GET
    @Produces({
        "application/json"
    })
    AccountWebUserIdResource.GetAccountByWebUserIdResponse getAccountByWebUserId(
@PathParam("webUserId")
        String webUserId,
        @QueryParam("sc")
        String sc,
        @QueryParam("fields")
        String fields)
        throws Exception
    ;
```

### Entity:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "href",
    "crm_member_id",
    "email_address",
    "account_status"
})
public class Account {

    /**
     * 
     * (Required)
     * 
     */
    @JsonProperty("href")
    private String href;
    /**
     * 
     * (Required)
     * 
     */
    @JsonProperty("crm_member_id")
    private String crmMemberId;
    /**
     * 
     * (Required)
     * 
     */
    @JsonProperty("email_address")
    private String emailAddress;
```

....

Answer (score 1):

At least with CXF-DOSGi 2 your code probably will not work. Loading the provider from a class name is problematic in OSGi anyway as the CXF DOSGi code has no visibility of the com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider class.

In CXF-DOSGi this can be done using an intent. This is more OSGi friendly as the JacksonJsonProvider is then directly used as a class and so OSGi class loading works nicely. It is also necessary to set a bus property to all to override the jacksonprovider as the spec normally would not allow this.

`cxf.bus.prop.skip.default.json.provider.registration=true`

The intent class looks like this:

```
@Component(property = "org.apache.cxf.dosgi.IntentName=jackson")
public class JacksonIntent implements Callable<List<Object>> {

    public List<Object> call() throws Exception {
        return Arrays.asList((Object)new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());
    }

}
```

The intents provide a generic way to define features and other overrides for CXF without directly influencing your service class.

The intent then has to be referenced in the service using the service property `service.exported.intents=jackson`.

I just added a [jackson example to CXF-DOSGi](https://github.com/apache/cxf-dosgi/tree/master/samples/rest/impl-jackson).

Another small obstacle is that the current `cxf-jackson` feature misses a bundle. See [CXF-7298](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-7298).